# How to export Apiary Blueprint as PDF, stand-alone HTML or similar "deliverable"?

Tags: html, css, export, blueprint, apiary.io

We need to export our [Apiary](http://apiary.io) Blueprint for task assignment purposes as a self containing "deliverable" like PDF or ZIP or similar. I'm aware of the [feature request](http://support.apiary.io/forums/120125-general/suggestions/3272523-allow-exporting-formatted-document-to-pdf-doc-rt) and the discussion below. Is it possible to "hack" something better than the poor html exporter? Maybe by injecting some css style into the page with chrome? Has somebody found a "good-enough" solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ján Sáreník mentioned [aglio](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio), you can make it work **locally** by the following steps.

- Save your API definition markdown (e.g. `myfile.md`)
- Install aglio `npm install aglio -g`
- Start aglio server `aglio -i myfile.md -s`
- Open `localhost:3000` and download the HTML file
- Hack the HTML by commenting out the `<div id="localFile" ...>...</div>` warning
- Hack the HTML by replacing `http://localhost:3000/` with empty string everywhere

Aaand it's done.

Comment: Aglio was an excellent suggestion by itself, but I appreciate you taking the time to give some instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio to render API Blueprint into static HTML files which can be zipped (or maybe also PDF-exported, but I haven't tried).

Comment: Aglio's HTML must be served from a web server to function, as it depends on external resources and browsers will not allow them to be loaded if read from local filesystem.

Comment: It can be hacked, see other answer.

Comment: Agilo has a bug. It drops trailing slashes from paths. Issue opened, no response so far. https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio/issues/222

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answers. https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio is a good way to go.
I just tested this, and following command works for using aglio in docker.

- build aglio

`docker build -t aglio .`

- create some folder and add files you want to cenvert (i used input)

`mkdir input`

`cp path_to_my_file input/input.md`

- run command

`docker run -v $(pwd)/input:/tmp -t aglio -i /tmp/input.md -o /tmp/output.html`